# Geocoder and Country Codes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to get this following piece of script to Alert or Console.Log the Country Code but it keeps giving me the full address.

Could someone please help me out here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         alert(results[2].formatted_address)
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data
        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually alerts twice. First time it is formatted address, second time the country.

For second alert- change `administrative_area_level_1` to `country`-

```
if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "country") {
```

Then if you alert `short_name` you'll get the country code.